# Can I insulate test writers from the details of a pytest fixture by requesting it from a non-top-level function?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm building some helper functions for other people to use when writing their pytest tests.

One thing that is going to be done frequently in these tests is to ask for a country's quota of a material, where the material might be "spam", "eggs", "sausage", etc.

It so happens that the best way to compute quotas is to do a database query and some post-processing that ends up returning all known quotas.  This generates a dictionary of most (but not all) of the country codes, each of which is a dictionary with most (but not all) of the materials as keys:

```
{ 'CA': { 'spam': 100, 'eggs': 50 },
  'US': { 'sausage': 25, 'spam': 100 },
  ... }
```

The reason I want to build a helper function, instead of just providing quotas directly to them as a fixture, is to protect the writers of individual tests from having to always say something like

```
def my_test( quotas ):
  if 'XY' not in quotas or 'spam' not in quotas['XY']:
    the_quota = 0
  else:
    the_quota = quotas['XY']['spam']
    ...
```

(and the reason they would have to do this is because we don't know up-front what all the possible materials are, so I can't just build a simple fixture that makes sure the dictionary is fully populated.)

I would just like them to be able to do

```
from helper_functions import quota

def my_test( ):
  the_quota = quota( 'XY','spam' )
```

and have my `quota` function handle the gory details.

How do I *do* that, though?  Or am I thinking about this all wrong?

Comment: I've just written up an answer, but now I realize I'm not answering your real question. The direct answer to your question is that of course, you can import a function from a helper module. But if you're asking, it must not be working for you. Have you tried, if so what have your tried, and what errors are you getting?

Comment: You can have a fixture that returns a function instead of the dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

I decided I don't understand pytest very well and am also thinking about it all wrong.

There are probably fancier and/or more 21st-century-object-y ways to do it, but I'm going to provide a test function that uses a module global variable to contain the initialized dictionary.

file helper_functions.py:

```
__quotas = {}

def lookup_quota( country, resource ):
  if not __quotas:
    initialize_quotas()
  if country not in quotas or resource not in quotas[country]:
    return(0)
  else:
    return quotas[country][resource]
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this solution. In a test harness, it's normal to do this kind of setup.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can see for solving this is to use a `defaultdict`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

quotas = {
   'CA': { 'spam': 100, 'eggs': 50 },
   'US': { 'sausage': 25, 'spam': 100 },
}
default_quotas = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
# default_quotas.update(quotas)  # doesn't work
for place, q in quotas.items():
    default_quotas[place].update(q)

print(default_quotas["CA"]["spam"])          # 100
print(default_quotas["CA"]["bacon"])         # 0
print(default_quotas["nowhere"]["nothing"])  # 0
```

Notes:

- I don't like having that loop to initialize `default_quotas`, but with the commented out line the inner dictionaries are regular dict's, not defaultdict's
- In case you haven't seen lambdas before, `lambda: defaultdict(int)` is an anonymous function that returns a defaultdict of ints, so that the top-level structure is a defaultdict of defaultdicts of ints.
- Warning: because I'm using defaultdict, anything you query gets inserted, so that after my three print statements those printed `0` values are actually stored in `default_quotas`.

Comment: I think defaultdict is interesting and may be useful in some situations - thank you.

But this dictionary-lookup example is just one of a few examples where I want to provide individual test writers a function, that behind the scenes happens to do some expensive stuff to initialize itself, so it seems convenient to use a fixture, but I don't want to have to expose that fact to them.

Comment: Yeah, I realized after writing it that this answer only provided a tangentially interesting idea, but not the real answer to your question.